# What is the correct way to add roles to existing users with Firebase authentication?

Tags: firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication, google-oauth

I am adding `admin` and `user` roles to an existing Firebase application that already has users with authentication.

In the Authentication section there is no way to add custom roles to an existing user. The custom roles documentation states that modifying [realtime database rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims#access_custom_claims_on_the_client) is the way forward, but to my knowledge I am not using realtime db.

What is the correct way to assign custom roles to existing application users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Authentication only handles **authentication**, so letting the user prove that they are who they say they are. On its own it has no component that does **authorization**, so nothing about providing access to resources to users.

Authorization is left to the back-end services that use the information from Firebase Authentication, like in the example that you gave Firebase's own Realtime Database. If you're not using the Realtime Database, then indeed that example is not relevant to you.

---

The correct way to implement authorization depends on the backend service you use.

For Firebase's Realtime Database, Cloud Storage, and Cloud Firestore, the authorization is handled through the server-side security rules of those products as documented [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/get-started).

If you're using Cloud Functions for your back-end, you can get the current user from the context for [Callable functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable?gen=2nd#write_and_deploy_the_callable_function) and Realtime Database functions, or pass the ID token along yourself and [decode/verify](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens) that for other types.

If you're using a custom backend, you'd do the same as for non-callable Cloud Functions:

1. Pass the ID token from your client to the custom backend over a secure connection.
2. [Decode and verify the ID token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens), and determine whether the user has permission based on that.

In many of these cases, it's up to you yourself to determine how you model authorization. The two most common options for this are:

- Set custom claims in the ID token itself, that are then passed along with every request.
- Store the authorization information in some external data source (like the Realtime Database or Cloud Firestore), and read it from there based on the UID when needed.

Both of these are valid approaches, and neither of them is pertinently better than the other. I typically tend to use custom claims for values that don't change after they're set (i.e. marking a user as an admin), and the database for most other types (i.e. a subscription status).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation, that has cleared it all up for me.